# Can't turn on Bluetooth in my MacBook Pro

Tags: bluetooth

I can't turn on Bluetooth on my MacBook Pro. The Bluetooth Icon has a diagonal line through it and I can't move the switch to On.

1. I tried pressing Shift and Option, clicking on Reset the Bluetooth Module and restarting the laptop. It didn't work.
2. I tried turning the Power Off and On. That didn't work.
3. Now when I try to turn on Bluetooth Preferences I get a small Pane saying
   "You can’t open the “Bluetooth” preferences pane because it is not available to you at this time." Underneath this it says, "To see this preferences pane, you may need to connect a device to your computer." So I connected my iPhone, but nothing happens.
   Any advice? Thanks

Comment:  menu > About this Mac > System Report… what does it say under Bluetooth. Also, what Mac, what OS?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your question re what it says under Bluetooth. I can't access Bluetooth Preferences. The icon has disappeared from Settings and I get the message I quoted above. It's. MacBook Pro reconditioned 2015 model. bought a couple of years ago, Mac OS Big Sur Version 11.4. BTW, I'm not an IT person.

Comment: Did you look at the system report yet? It has a set of hardware labels on the left… one is Bluetooth. The label will show whether your Mac recognises that it has bluetooth hardware installed

Comment: It says "No Information Found". .... so... I suppose that means it either doesn't recognise that it has bluetooth hardware installed... or Mayne it no longer works..? What is your opinion Tetsujin?

Comment: It's either broken or disconnected. Depending on your skill-level, either take it apart to check or replace, or give to to Apple for repair.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Tetsujin, Skill level zero so it'll have to be Apple repair.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem with an NVRAM/PRAM reset. Instructions below are from [Apple's Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.
>
> - On Mac computers that play a startup sound, you can release the keys after the second startup sound.
> - On Mac computers that have the Apple T2 Security Chip, you can release the keys after the Apple logo appears and disappears for the second time.